# How do I remove Bedtime in IOS 13

Tags: alarm

Even though I have Bedtime turned off in IOS 13, it still appears in my alarms, eating up screen space at the price of all my custom alarms that I do use.

Worse, the IOS update turned on Bedtime wake up and set off the alarm hours before I needed to be up today. I’m typing this when I should still be asleep. Stinks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately it seems as thought for now IOS 13.1.3 does not have an option to remove once setup. There seems to be a lot of push back so this may change.

However, in the meantime you can under the bedtime tab in the clock app select the "Bedtime option and disable it, and then go back and ensure that alarms are set and reconfigure if needed.

Ultimately at this time if you have automatic backups turned on and you know when you enabled it you can erase all content and settings which will factory reset your phone and then  restore from that specific backup.

Comment: Yep, I disabled it. I just dislike that I can’t exclude it from the screen. 

Restoring from backup is a great idea. However, I didn’t take the sensible approach of backing up before updates like I do habitually with my workstations. You gave me a good “wake up call,” if you’ll pardon the expression.

Answer (score 0):

Hmmm... strange move from Apple. I never had the issue while in beta versions of iOS 13 and 13.1.

All I can say is that on iOS 13.2 beta, the setting is available in the Clock app (screen capture in French, but you’ll understand for sure):

[image: iOS 13.2 Clock App]